# Spring AOP introductions not working with && this(IntroducedInterface)

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I have following aspect

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass{
   @DeclareParents(value="com.mac.model.*",defaultImpl=Impl.class)
   public IntroduceInterface inter;

   @Pointcut("execution(* com.mac.Employee.display(..))")
   public void empPointcut(){}

  @Before("empPointCut() && this(introduceInterface)")
  public void BeforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp,IntroduceInterface inf){
  inf.introMethod();
  }
}
```

and I am trying to replicate code from spring docs which is like below:

```
@Aspect
public class UsageTracking {

    @DeclareParents(value="com.xzy.myapp.service.*+", defaultImpl=DefaultUsageTracked.class)
    public static UsageTracked mixin;

    @Before("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.businessService() && this(usageTracked)")
    public void recordUsage(UsageTracked usageTracked) {
        usageTracked.incrementUseCount();
    }

}
```

but its not working its giving error :
IllegalArgumentException error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Its a simple spring application .What could be reason its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Name in here

```
@Before("empPointCut() && this(_name_in_here_)")
```

should be the same as in

```
public void BeforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp,IntroduceInterface _name_in_here_){
```

So this should work fine:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectClass{
   @DeclareParents(value="com.mac.model.*",defaultImpl=Impl.class)
   public IntroduceInterface inter;

   @Pointcut("execution(* com.mac.Employee.display(..))")
   public void empPointcut(){}

  @Before("empPointCut() && this(inf)")
  public void BeforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp,IntroduceInterface inf){
  inf.introMethod();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried above code. But it still gives me same error.

Comment: Note: If I dont use this() and parameter in before advice and execute below in my main application class its working without any error:

(IntroduceInterface) iof=(IntroduceInterface) context.getBean("emp");
iof.introMethod(); 
**which means introduction is happening** 
what is wrong with Before advice :(

Comment: is Employee really  under _com.mac_ package, not the _com.mac.model_ ? Maybe you made a mistake in pointCut path to Employee

Comment: No Employee is under com.mac.model

Comment: com.mac -- App.java here I am loading Application context and have files IntroducedInterface.java and IntroducedInterfaceImpl.java under same package then ,

com.mac.config.config.java in this file i have above code with Aspect annotation

com.mac.model.Employee.java this the bean on which i have pointcut

Comment: `@Pointcut("execution(* com.mac.Employee.display(..))")
   public void empPointcut(){}`
seems like here Employee is under wrong package

Comment: Oh sry i missed it in the question
actually it is @Pointcut("execution(* com.mac.model.Employee.display(..))") in my code

Comment: please check if you have imported `org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;` and not anything else

Comment: could you try to add  `@Component` to your `AspectClass` ? so it would have both `@Aspect` and `@Component`

Comment: It already have it.
`@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@Aspect
public class AspectClass{..}`

Comment: Does it has `@Configuration` annotation ?

Comment: in my `@configuration` class which is config.java i am having 
@ComponentScan(basepackagesClasses={AspectClass.class}) and this Config.java is in com.mac.config package which is same as AspectClass.java

Comment: Could you please post more details to the question, your config classes, employee, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Annotation object is available to the advice via the annotation parameter. So both names (method parameter name and annotation declared inside pointcut expression) should be same.

Please take a look at these two sections from spring documentation - [Passing parameters to advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing).

From Spring doc:

The proxy object ( this), target object ( target), and annotations ( @within, @target, @annotation, @args) can all be bound in a similar fashion. The following example shows how you could match the execution of methods annotated with an @Auditable annotation, and extract the audit code.

First the definition of the @Auditable annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Auditable {
    AuditCode value();
}
```

And then the advice that matches the execution of @Auditable methods:

```
@Before("com.xyz.lib.Pointcuts.anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(**auditable**)")
public void audit(Auditable **auditable**) {
    AuditCode code = auditable.value();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok got your point that both names (method parameter name and annotation declared inside pointcut expression) should be same. But its still not working.

Comment: Could you please add the complete stack trace?

Comment: Its not the complete stack trace but it should suffice. 

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name "org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor": initialization of bean failed nestes exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Comment: Note: If I dont use this() and parameter in before advice and execute below in my main application class its working without any error: (IntroduceInterface) iof=(IntroduceInterface) context.getBean("emp"); iof.introMethod(); which means introduction is happening what is wrong with Before advice :( –

Comment: Okay.. can you try getting rid of JoinPoint jp from method argument? Please check whether it works.. Also what is the package structure of JoinPoint?

Comment: com.mac -- App.java      here I am loading Application context
                -- IntroducedInterface.java
                -- Impl.java
com.mac.config.config.java         in this file i have above code with Aspect annotation
com.mac.model.Employee.java   this the bean on which i have pointcut

Comment: Correction in question : 
missed .model in the question actual pointcut is 
@Pointcut("execution(* com.mac.model.Employee.display(..))")